# TypeIT not finishing writing

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a custom function for TypeIT (https://typeitjs.com/) because I need to add commands from dynamically.

To create a new TypeIt object I'm doing this way:

```
/* global variable to store typer */
currentTyper = '';

function createTyper(typeSpeed, deleteSpeed)
{
    //Creates new typer
    currentTyper = new TypeIt(type_div_id, {
        speed: typeSpeed,
        deleteSpeed: deleteSpeed,
        afterComplete: (instance) => {
            cursor: false
        }
    });

    //FOR TESTING
    addParameterToTyper(TyperTypeEnum.TYPE, 'WHYYYYY');
    addParameterToTyper(TyperTypeEnum.PAUSE, 1000);
    addParameterToTyper(TyperTypeEnum.GO, '');
}
```

For adding the parameters to my typer object I'm using the following code:

```
function addParameterToTyper(typerENUM, value)
{
    switch (typerENUM)
    {
        case TyperTypeEnum.TYPE:
            if(value)
            {
                currentTyper.type(value);
            }
            break;
        case TyperTypeEnum.PAUSE:
            currentTyper.pause(value);
            break;
        case TyperTypeEnum.GO:
            currentTyper.go();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the "type" command works but the "pause" command it's not working.

Another problem that I'm having is that the "afterComplete" function never runs so my cursor never disappears.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Creator of TypeIt here. A couple things I noticed:

- The `pause` method is used when constructing the queue you're going to type. It must be called *before* `go()`. If you want to freeze and unfreeze the instance after it's started, you can use those methods respectively: https://typeitjs.com/docs#pausing--resuming
- Your `afterComplete` method call isn't using valid JavaScript. Your example is treating the function body as an object, which won't do anything. If you're looking to remove the cursor after completion, you can use the `.destroy()` method when that callback fires: https://codepen.io/alexmacarthur/pen/jOPNNJG

If you want to dig around the site a little more, you'll find many more examples and documentation that should help you out: https://typeitjs.com/

Hope that helps some!